# using Set<Object> in model in Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, set

I have a User model at below:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User{

    @Id
    private String _id;
    @Indexed(unique = true, direction = IndexDirection.DESCENDING, dropDups = true)
    private String username;
    private String pass;
    private String fullname;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    private Long score;

    @DBRef
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

and I call a method to get all User:

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public List<User> findAllUser(){
    return users.findAll(); 
}
```

But the problem has occurred:

```
Failed to instantiate java.util.Set using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
```

Could you help me?
What should I do with the User model?
Thank you!

Comment: add sample document from your collection user

Comment: Thank you. I found my problem. Because I have more User not map with my model. After I deleted their, everything work ok